Error en Postman con MYSQL en Macbook Pro 14 M2
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
No puedo conectar Postman con Mysql. No se si puede estar mal instalado el Mysql pero el Phpmyadmin esta funcionando.
Por favor me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema o si conocen algun sitio donde existan profesores en linea que puedan ayudar. De ante mano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Desconozco si se puede conectar Postman directamente con MySQL, pero en la captura de pantalla veo que tratas de conectar a una API api.ecommerce.com. Cabe destacar que ese dominio existe en internet. Si el servidor de la API es local, se llama ecommerce.com y tu equipo está conectado a internet, tendrás que crear un host para desviar el enrutamiento hacia el servidor de las pruebas. Hace falta más información de cómo es tu entorno y de lo que realmente quieres hacer.

Hola este dominio lo configure con dominios virtuales de forma local en mi Macbook pro 14 M2

Si te fijas tú Macbook pro 14 M2 te indica un error 404, lo cual significa que tu Macbook pro 14 M2 tiene un servidor web correctamente levantado pero que la ruta no es correcta en tu Macbook pro 14 M2, no creo que sea problema de tu Macbook pro 14 M2 si no que tienes algo mal configurado o sencillamente /categories no existe
